# Do ultralights need to have EPA-compliant engines in the USA and Canada?

Tags: faa-regulations, piston-engine, ultralight, transport-canada

Do ultralights need to have EPA-compliant engines in:

1. The USA?
2. Canada?

Just wondering if you could use a hobby type 2 stroke engine for a twin engine Lazair type ultralight.  I don't think they are EPA compliant.

I know some people use them.  Just wondering if it's actually legal?

Answer (score 3):

No such thing as EPA compliance on General Aviation engines or ultralight engines for that matter.  You buy a piston engine from Continental or Lycoming, it has no pollution controls of any kind. It's like it's 1960.  There just aren't enough of them to make any real impact, so they get a pass.

Pretty much anything goes for a Part 103 Ultralight in the US or what is called a "Basic Ultralight" in Canada.  Whatever suits you.

Comment: "Aren't enough of them to make any real impact" is arguable when general aviation engines spew lead out of their exhausts.

Comment: The lead pollution is inconsequential in the general scheme of things.  Microscopic compared to leaded fuel in cars.  If you grounded the GA fleet it would make no difference to anything that you could measure.  Me, I use auto fuel in my plane. The low octane engine is WAY happier on that.

Comment: I disagree sir, I think that lead from GA plane exhaust may make a big difference to families with children living near busy GA airports.

Comment: It's like fretting over a guy smoking a cigarette across the street.  In any case the rules we are talking about with respect to engines themselves have nothing to do with leaded fuel.